# How to set reminder using my app?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created custom calendar with the help of MBCalender kit and I have add events for some specific dates now, how can I create reminder for those specific dates?

Answer (score 0):

By using EKReminder

```
- (void)createReminder:(NSDate*) objDate {
    EKReminder *reminder = [EKReminder
                            reminderWithEventStore:objEventStore];

    // objEventStore is the object of EKEventStore if you create that global that will be good

    reminder.title = @"title";
    reminder.notes = @"note";

    reminder.calendar = [objAppDelegate.eventStore defaultCalendarForNewReminders];

    EKAlarm *alarm = [EKAlarm alarmWithAbsoluteDate:objDate];

    [reminder addAlarm:alarm];

    NSError *error = nil;

    BOOL status  = [objAppDelegate.eventStore saveReminder:reminder commit:YES error:&error];
    if (status == NO) {
        _strUDID = nil;
    }
    else  {
        _strUDID = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",reminder.calendarItemIdentifier];
    }

}
```